# How to set and get data using SharedPreferences?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

Previously i do SharedPreferences to get user name. That was okay.

from API Response

```
"status": 200,
    "message": "Login Successfully",
    "result": {
        "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9mYzBhLTIwMi0xODctMy01Lm5ncm9rLmlvXC9hcGlcL2F1dGhcL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNjM5OTAxMDQ0LCJleHAiOjE2Mzk5ODc0NDQsIm5iZiI6MTYzOTkwMTA0NCwianRpIjoidndLWHlOYlJmTXdzMlFZbCIsInN1YiI6MiwicHJ2IjoiODdlMGFmMWVmOWZkMTU4MTJmZGVjOTcxNTNhMTRlMGIwNDc1NDZhYSJ9.Tr_CTZeKX6M2pycRal7CGeQ0i3FA3Fco0Xm5dwtWwDA",
        "user": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "hani",
```

Set and get

```
 if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        message = "Login Success";
      });
      print(res.body);
      SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      localStorage.setString('user', json.encode(body['result']['user']));

  String name;

_loadUserData() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var user = jsonDecode(localStorage.getString('user'));

    if (user != null) {
      setState(() {
        name = user['name'];
      });
    }
  }
```

But if i want to get the id from this API Response, what should i write?
to set and get that id using SharedPreferences.

Or there's another way to get that id?

```
"status": "success",
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "exercise_name": "Reading Set 1",
            "exercise_type_id": 1,
            "show": 1,
            "finalized": 1,
            "created_at": "2021-12-17T07:13:50.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-12-17T20:47:57.000000Z",
            "total": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "exercise_name": "Reading Set 2",
            "exercise_type_id": 1,
            "show": 1,
            "finalized": 1,
            "created_at": "2021-12-17T20:34:50.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-12-17T20:46:15.000000Z",
            "total": 0
        }
    ]
```

Sorry, I new to coding and flutter.
Hope someone can help

Answer (score 0):

In the first response `result` is a `JSONObject` but in the second one it is `JSONArray`.

```dart
if (res.statusCode == 200) {
//do what ever you want

    final data = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    for (var exercise in data['result']) {
        //Now you can access each item
        if(exercise['exercise_name']== 'Reading Set 1'){
         //Store ID in SharedPrefrence
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how to store ID in sharedpreferences? it is still same as i do previously? declare sharedpreferences and set?

Comment: @fatin . Yes. You can store one Id or store a list of Ids in `sharedpreferences`